# How to pass arguments to an event handler function and still use 'this' reference?

Tags: javascript

I have a situation (using the Raphael library) where I have this:

```
rect.click(doSomething);
```

And within `doSomething()`, I can get the bounding box size:

```
var boxSize = this.getBBox();
```

The problem is, what if I want to pass an argument to doSomething? If I do, then the `this` reference breaks for some reason. How can I pass in an argument and still use `this`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap the listener in another function, and use [`.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to call the function with given parameters:

```
var foo = 123, bar = 'blabla';
rect.click(function(event) {
    return doSomething.call(this, event, foo, bar);
});
```